# Should I nofollow a link to a noindex page?

Tags: seo, nofollow, noindex

If I have a page on my blog that is marked noindex or blocked by robots.txt should I mark all links within my blog that point to that page as `rel="nofollow"` or not?

*Example:*

I publish a post on my blog and mark it as noindex. That post will show up on my blog's front page and all links on the front page are do follow. So when a bot comes on the main page it crawls all the links but when the bot gets to the link to a noindex post does it take note that the link and crawl that page?

Comment: Should not matter. But if it is an easy thing to do, then it should not hurt. If it is a bother, then I would not worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I nofollow a link to a noindex page?

As a general rule, `nofollow` should only be used on links to pages of external websites you don't trust or you don't recommend. There is no reason to set `nofollow` on internal pages or links. So in your case, the answer is no.

> but when the bot gets to the link to a noindex post, does he note that link,
>       but doesn't index the page or what?

The bot follows the link, identifies the page, but does not pass it for evaluation and indexation. It extracts all the links from the `noindex` post and tries to follow them too. So, yes this is correct.

You can read more in my personal articles about [when to use `nofollow`](http://ligatures.net/content/expertise/how-to-use-robots-meta-tags.html#NOINDEXNOFOLLOW), and about the [indexation process](http://ligatures.net/content/expertise/indexing-process-introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it, while making a page no-index only nofollows all the links on that page (not links to it from other pages), making it nofollow isn't going to help you at all. Follow or nofollow, each outbound link is spreading out the internal balance of SEO juice (or PageRank). In other words, you can't really do structure/sculpting by using internal, nofollow links anymore.